# email already exists while updating user in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was updating the **User** when faced *email already exists* crossed my way.
how ever i could use the `extra_kwargs` to overcome the `email already exists` or `phone already exists` issue. and then using `from django.core.validators import EmailValidator` in **extra_kwargs** as `"email": {"validators": [EmailValidator]}`.. bring back my email field validations.

but that don't seems as a **real solution**.
As we are just **updating** the existing model object.. why It's behaving like we are creating a new one.

I think there should be something as defining `update` or `partial_update` or i don't know what ever.. **is there any other solutions for this** ??

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "id", "full_name", "gender", "phone", "email", "date_of_birth"
        extra_kwargs = {
            # "phone": {"validators": []},
            # "email": {"validators": [EmailValidator]},
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, by default `email` field in User django is not unique, if want to change unique in database, you can use [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/), it will automatic detect unique in your serializer, and cannot save user with already exists email.

Then assume, we are not using AbstracUser, so we need to validate unique email manually in our serializer. We can use 2 ways:

**1. [UniqueValidator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator)**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "full_name", "gender", "phone", "email", "date_of_birth"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "email": {
                "validators": [
                    EmailValidator
                    UniqueValidator(
                       queryset=User.objects.all(),
                       message="This email already exist!"
                    )
                ]
            },
        }
```

**2. Validate Email Manually**:
In our serializer, just add function to validate email

```
def validate_email(self, value):
    if User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
       raise serializers.ValidationError("This email already exists!.")
    return value
```

CMIIW